# How to install XimeraLaTeX

Tags: packages

I am trying to install Ximera on my Windows 10 machine as indicated [here](https://ximera.osu.edu/introduction/gettingStarted/installingLocallyWindows/installingLocally). That site says I need to install XimeraLaTeX and says that instructions can be found on its Git repository [here](https://github.com/XimeraProject/ximeraLatex). However, this repository links back to the first page under its install instructions. Does anyone have any suggestions, or am I somehow missing the instructions?

Also, I apparently need to install Xake, but there are no instructions at all as to how to install that.

Comment: The Github page links to https://ximera.osu.edu/introduction/gettingStarted/overviewForInstalling/overviewForInstalling, a page that has a Next button that shows detailed instructions for Windows and other operating systems.

Comment: @Marijn The link you provide is the first one in my post. It tells you that you need to install XimeraLaTeX and Xake but does not provide instructions (other than sending you to the Github page) as I indicated in my post.

Comment: Clicking Next two times on that page leads to https://ximera.osu.edu/introduction/gettingStarted/installingLocallyWindows/installingLocally, stating _Install ximeraLaTeX: Visit the repo on Github.com XimeraProject/ximeraLatex GitHub page and click the “Clone in Desktop” button, Create the directory structure `C:\localtexmf\tex\latex\`_, etc., providing a full step by step guide to installing the system.

Comment: @Marijn I don't know what was happening previously, but before when I clicked next it took me to the mac instructions, but after pressing the flashing "update" button when I followed your link it took me to a page I had never seen before! Thank you so much.